# sqlalchemy: How to error on assignment of unknown column?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Is there a mixin or other mechanism I can use to cause immediate failure if I assign to unknown column on a model instance?

```py
 new_order = Order()  # Order is a SQLAlchemy model class
 new_order.this_column_does_not_exist = 42  # I want this to raise!
```

The [documentation on Constructors and Object Initialization](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html#constructors-and-object-initialization) says

> You are free to [...] assign attributes to the instance that are unknown to the ORM

which is in keeping with the conventions of Python, but **I'm wondering if there is a way to opt-in to a strict mode of enforcement to avoid latent errors due to typos in column name assignments**.

Comment: @das-g: Yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out.